# Program for an upright and inverted triangle pattern with one For loop and if-else statement

Tags: python

I am new to Python and wanted to create a program which prints this star pattern using one `for` loop and an if-else statement:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

What I've done so far:

```
stars = "*"
for i in range (0,10):
    if i <5:
        print(stars)
        stars = stars + "*"
   # else:
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Not sure what to put in the else statement?

I've tried looking online but all solutions I've seen use two `for` loops, which makes sense. Is it possible to use one loop?

Comment: To avoid confusion, note that this is not Pascal's triangle. First, Pascal's triangle is mathematical, consisting of numbers. Second, Pascal's triangle is shaped differently; it doesn't get narrower.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Do you know the correct name for this pattern? Does it have one?

Comment: I don't think the pattern has an "official" name. From some investigation, it looks like someone made up "right pascal triangle" as a programming interview question and it has been copied around programming sites ever since. The earliest instance I could find is 2019: https://medium.com/edureka/pattern-programs-in-java-f33186c711c8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is is to increase the number of stars in each row up to a certain point, and then decrease the number of stars in each subsequent row.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
stars = "*"
for i in range(1, 9):
    if i <= 4:
        print(stars)
        stars = stars + "*"
    else:
        print(stars)
        stars = stars[:-1]
print("*")
```

Comment: Thank you. What does [:-1] mean? Why don't we put -1 before the :?

Comment: @Thandi i used `[:-1]`  to remove the last character from the string stars.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question because there's no explicit *for* loop and there's no conditional test.

```
W = 9

stars = ["*"*i for i in range(1, W//2+2)]

print(*(stars + stars[-2::-1]), sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

**Note:**

Only works when W > 0 and is an odd integer